# Croppic not working in Codeigniter

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter, croppic

I am using Croppic http://www.croppic.net/ to crop images in codeigniter. The problem is it is working in core php but not working in codeigniter. I am using it with minimal configuration. Please help to solve my issue below is my Code

> View: crop.php

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"/>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
    <meta name="description" content=""/>
    <meta name="author" content=""/>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="assets/img/favicon.png"/>

    <title>croppic</title>

     <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
    <!-- <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>-->
   <link href="<?=base_url()?>assets/croppic/css/main.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <link href="<?=base_url()?>assets/croppic/css/croppic.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/assets/css/bootstrap.css"/></style>
    <!-- Fonts from Google Fonts -->
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:300,400,900' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'/>
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Mrs+Sheppards&subset=latin,latin-ext' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'/>



  </head>

  <body>


    <div class="container">
        <div class="row mt ">
            <div class="col-lg-4 ">
                <h4 class="centered"> Minimal Controls </h4>
                <p class="centered">( define the controls available )</p>
                <div id="cropContainerMinimal"></div>
            </div>      
            <div class="col-lg-4 ">
                <div id="cropContainerPlaceHolder2"></div>
            </div>
        </div>      
    </div>


    <!-- /container -->






    <script src=" https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="<?=base_url()?>assets/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="<?=base_url()?>assets/croppic/js/jquery.mousewheel.min.js"></script>
    <script src="<?=base_url()?>assets/croppic/js/croppic.min.js"></script>
        <script src="<?=base_url()?>assets/croppic/js/main.js"></script>

    <script>


        var croppicContaineroutputMinimal = {
                uploadUrl:"<?=base_url()?>img_save_to_file/img_save_file",
                cropUrl:"<?=base_url()?>img_crop_to_file/img_crop_file", 
                modal:false,
                doubleZoomControls:false,
                rotateControls: false,
                loaderHtml:'<div class="loader bubblingG"><span id="bubblingG_1"></span><span id="bubblingG_2"></span><span id="bubblingG_3"></span></div> ',
                onBeforeImgUpload: function(){ console.log('onBeforeImgUpload') },
                onAfterImgUpload: function(){ console.log('onAfterImgUpload') },
                onImgDrag: function(){ console.log('onImgDrag') },
                onImgZoom: function(){ console.log('onImgZoom') },
                onBeforeImgCrop: function(){ console.log('onBeforeImgCrop') },
                onAfterImgCrop:function(){ console.log('onAfterImgCrop') },
                onReset:function(){ console.log('onReset') },
                onError:function(errormessage){ console.log('onError:'+errormessage) }
        }
        var cropContaineroutput = new Croppic('cropContainerMinimal', croppicContaineroutputMinimal);




    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

> Controller: img_crop_to_file.php

```
<?php



Class Img_crop_to_file extends CI_Controller {

public function __construct() {
parent::__construct();

// Load form helper library
$this->load->helper('form');

// Load form validation library
$this->load->library('form_validation');

// Load session library
$this->load->library('session');
}
/*  img_crop_to_file.php
*   !!! THIS IS JUST AN EXAMPLE !!!, PLEASE USE ImageMagick or some other quality image processing libraries
*/

public function img_crop_file() {
$imgUrl = $_POST['imgUrl'];
// original sizes
$imgInitW = $_POST['imgInitW'];
$imgInitH = $_POST['imgInitH'];
// resized sizes
$imgW = $_POST['imgW'];
$imgH = $_POST['imgH'];
// offsets
$imgY1 = $_POST['imgY1'];
$imgX1 = $_POST['imgX1'];
// crop box
$cropW = $_POST['cropW'];
$cropH = $_POST['cropH'];
// rotation angle
$angle = $_POST['rotation'];

$jpeg_quality = 100;

$output_filename = base_url()."temp/croppedImg_".rand();

// uncomment line below to save the cropped image in the same location as the original image.
//$output_filename = dirname($imgUrl). "/croppedImg_".rand();

$what = getimagesize($imgUrl);

switch(strtolower($what['mime']))
{
    case 'image/png':
        $img_r = imagecreatefrompng($imgUrl);
        $source_image = imagecreatefrompng($imgUrl);
        $type = '.png';
        break;
    case 'image/jpeg':
        $img_r = imagecreatefromjpeg($imgUrl);
        $source_image = imagecreatefromjpeg($imgUrl);
        error_log("jpg");
        $type = '.jpeg';
        break;
    case 'image/gif':
        $img_r = imagecreatefromgif($imgUrl);
        $source_image = imagecreatefromgif($imgUrl);
        $type = '.gif';
        break;
    default: die('image type not supported');
}


//Check write Access to Directory

if(!is_writable(dirname($output_filename))){
    $response = Array(
        "status" => 'error',
        "message" => 'Can`t write cropped File'
    );  
}else{

    // resize the original image to size of editor
    $resizedImage = imagecreatetruecolor($imgW, $imgH);
    imagecopyresampled($resizedImage, $source_image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $imgW, $imgH, $imgInitW, $imgInitH);
    // rotate the rezized image
    $rotated_image = imagerotate($resizedImage, -$angle, 0);
    // find new width & height of rotated image
    $rotated_width = imagesx($rotated_image);
    $rotated_height = imagesy($rotated_image);
    // diff between rotated & original sizes
    $dx = $rotated_width - $imgW;
    $dy = $rotated_height - $imgH;
    // crop rotated image to fit into original rezized rectangle
    $cropped_rotated_image = imagecreatetruecolor($imgW, $imgH);
    imagecolortransparent($cropped_rotated_image, imagecolorallocate($cropped_rotated_image, 0, 0, 0));
    imagecopyresampled($cropped_rotated_image, $rotated_image, 0, 0, $dx / 2, $dy / 2, $imgW, $imgH, $imgW, $imgH);
    // crop image into selected area
    $final_image = imagecreatetruecolor($cropW, $cropH);
    imagecolortransparent($final_image, imagecolorallocate($final_image, 0, 0, 0));
    imagecopyresampled($final_image, $cropped_rotated_image, 0, 0, $imgX1, $imgY1, $cropW, $cropH, $cropW, $cropH);
    // finally output png image
    //imagepng($final_image, $output_filename.$type, $png_quality);
    imagejpeg($final_image, $output_filename.$type, $jpeg_quality);
    $response = Array(
        "status" => 'success',
        "url" => $output_filename.$type
    );
}
echo json_encode($response);
}
}
?>
```

> Controller: img_save_to_file.php

```
<?php



Class Img_crop_to_file extends CI_Controller {

public function __construct() {
parent::__construct();

// Load form helper library
$this->load->helper('form');

// Load form validation library
$this->load->library('form_validation');

// Load session library
$this->load->library('session');
}
/*  img_crop_to_file.php
*   !!! THIS IS JUST AN EXAMPLE !!!, PLEASE USE ImageMagick or some other quality image processing libraries
*/

public function img_crop_file() {
$imgUrl = $_POST['imgUrl'];
// original sizes
$imgInitW = $_POST['imgInitW'];
$imgInitH = $_POST['imgInitH'];
// resized sizes
$imgW = $_POST['imgW'];
$imgH = $_POST['imgH'];
// offsets
$imgY1 = $_POST['imgY1'];
$imgX1 = $_POST['imgX1'];
// crop box
$cropW = $_POST['cropW'];
$cropH = $_POST['cropH'];
// rotation angle
$angle = $_POST['rotation'];

$jpeg_quality = 100;

$output_filename = base_url()."temp/croppedImg_".rand();

// uncomment line below to save the cropped image in the same location as the original image.
//$output_filename = dirname($imgUrl). "/croppedImg_".rand();

$what = getimagesize($imgUrl);

switch(strtolower($what['mime']))
{
    case 'image/png':
        $img_r = imagecreatefrompng($imgUrl);
        $source_image = imagecreatefrompng($imgUrl);
        $type = '.png';
        break;
    case 'image/jpeg':
        $img_r = imagecreatefromjpeg($imgUrl);
        $source_image = imagecreatefromjpeg($imgUrl);
        error_log("jpg");
        $type = '.jpeg';
        break;
    case 'image/gif':
        $img_r = imagecreatefromgif($imgUrl);
        $source_image = imagecreatefromgif($imgUrl);
        $type = '.gif';
        break;
    default: die('image type not supported');
}


//Check write Access to Directory

if(!is_writable(dirname($output_filename))){
    $response = Array(
        "status" => 'error',
        "message" => 'Can`t write cropped File'
    );  
}else{

    // resize the original image to size of editor
    $resizedImage = imagecreatetruecolor($imgW, $imgH);
    imagecopyresampled($resizedImage, $source_image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $imgW, $imgH, $imgInitW, $imgInitH);
    // rotate the rezized image
    $rotated_image = imagerotate($resizedImage, -$angle, 0);
    // find new width & height of rotated image
    $rotated_width = imagesx($rotated_image);
    $rotated_height = imagesy($rotated_image);
    // diff between rotated & original sizes
    $dx = $rotated_width - $imgW;
    $dy = $rotated_height - $imgH;
    // crop rotated image to fit into original rezized rectangle
    $cropped_rotated_image = imagecreatetruecolor($imgW, $imgH);
    imagecolortransparent($cropped_rotated_image, imagecolorallocate($cropped_rotated_image, 0, 0, 0));
    imagecopyresampled($cropped_rotated_image, $rotated_image, 0, 0, $dx / 2, $dy / 2, $imgW, $imgH, $imgW, $imgH);
    // crop image into selected area
    $final_image = imagecreatetruecolor($cropW, $cropH);
    imagecolortransparent($final_image, imagecolorallocate($final_image, 0, 0, 0));
    imagecopyresampled($final_image, $cropped_rotated_image, 0, 0, $imgX1, $imgY1, $cropW, $cropH, $cropW, $cropH);
    // finally output png image
    //imagepng($final_image, $output_filename.$type, $png_quality);
    imagejpeg($final_image, $output_filename.$type, $jpeg_quality);
    $response = Array(
        "status" => 'success',
        "url" => $output_filename.$type
    );
}
echo json_encode($response);
}
}
?>
```

Comment: getting any error  ..?

Comment: @Yash : The above code gives alert message - Can't upload File, no write Access

Comment: Check your folder permission .... Give it write access if not.

Comment: @Yash: I have checked folder has proper permission. Please look at this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31775477/error-when-crop-image-croppic-ci same problem but when i tried it is not working and the solution is also not good enough.

Comment: so Croppic still not working in Codeigniter ?